# ConvertFrom-String using a template not parsing as expected

Tags: parsing, powershell

I am trying to leverage the new [ConvertFrom-String](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2014/10/31/convertfrom-string-example-based-text-parsing.aspx) commandlet in the [Windows Management Production Preview 5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48729).

I have a `$Sample` of the string I am trying to parse data from and the `$Template` that I am using.

I am getting most of the data that I am looking for but for some reason am not getting all of it.

I have read a [number](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2014/10/31/convertfrom-string-example-based-text-parsing.aspx) [of](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/09/09/using-the-convertfrom-string-cmdlet-to-parse-structured-text/) [blog](http://www.lazywinadmin.com/2014/09/powershell-convertfrom-string-and.html) [articles](http://www.happysysadm.com/2014/11/first-look-at-convertfrom-string-in.html) about the topic and have trouble shot the parsing with [ConvertFrom-String Buddy](https://gist.github.com/dfinke/7b8197a2d8f914749f20) but am not able to get it to extract all of the data I need.

Can you please give me insight into what I might be doing wrong that is causing most of the data to be captured but not all of it?

Thank you in advance for any help or insight.

PowerShell Version:

```
PS C:\Users\alozano\Desktop> $psversiontable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10514  6
```

Here is the powershell code being run:

```
$Sample = @"
  JJK072821.12Z1220126.23630-01.S.JABI  
  +20.0               DARKNESS          
  6 IPS               PRINT SPEED       
  +000                TEAR OFF          
  APPLICATOR          PRINT MODE        
  NON-CONTINUOUS      MEDIA TYPE        
  WEB                 SENSOR TYPE       
  DIRECT-THERMAL      PRINT METHOD      
  812                 PRINT WIDTH       
  1874                LABEL LENGTH      
  9.0IN    228MM      MAXIMUM LENGTH    
  DISABLED            SUPPLIES WARNING  
  MAINT. OFF          EARLY WARNING     
  CONNECTED           USB COMM.         
  READY               EXTERNAL 5V       
  BIDIRECTIONAL       PARALLEL COMM.    
  RS232               SERIAL COMM.      
  9600                BAUD              
  8 BITS              DATA BITS         
  NONE                PARITY            
  XON/XOFF            HOST HANDSHAKE    
  NONE                PROTOCOL          
  000                 NETWORK ID        
  NORMAL MODE         COMMUNICATIONS    
  <~>  7EH            CONTROL PREFIX    
  <^>  5EH            FORMAT PREFIX     
  <,>  2CH            DELIMITER CHAR    
  ZPL II              ZPL MODE          
  ACTIVE              COMMAND OVERRIDE  
  NO MOTION           MEDIA POWER UP    
  NO MOTION           HEAD CLOSE        
  OFF                 BACKFEED          
  +080                LABEL TOP         
  +0000               LEFT POSITION     
  OFF                 VERIFIER PORT     
  MODE 1              APPLICATOR PORT   
  ENABLED             ERROR ON PAUSE    
  PULSE MODE          START PRINT SIG   
  FEED MODE           RESYNCH MODE      
  DISABLED            REPRINT MODE      
  048                 WEB S.            
  079                 MEDIA S.          
  065                 RIBBON S.         
  100                 TAKE LABEL        
  050                 MARK S.           
  000                 MARK MED S.       
  002                 TRANS GAIN        
  040                 TRANS BASE        
  086                 TRANS BRIGHT      
  082                 RIBBON GAIN       
  000                 MARK GAIN         
  DPCSWFX.            MODES ENABLED     
  .......M            MODES DISABLED    
   832 8/MM FULL      RESOLUTION        
  V53.17.21Z <-       FIRMWARE          
  1.3                 XML SCHEMA        
  V45 ---------- 19   HARDWARE ID       
  CUSTOMIZED          CONFIGURATION     
  10840k...........R: RAM               
  2048k............E: ONBOARD FLASH     
  NONE                FORMAT CONVERT    
  *** APPLICATOR      P34 INTERFACE     
                      TWINAX/COAX ID    
  FW VERSION          IDLE DISPLAY      
  11/05/15            RTC DATE          
  11:22               RTC TIME          
  DISABLED            ZBI               
  2.1                 ZBI VERSION       
  2,641,289 IN        NONRESET CNTR     
  2,641,289 IN        RESET CNTR1       
  2,641,289 IN        RESET CNTR2       
  6,708,875 CM        NONRESET CNTR     
  6,708,875 CM        RESET CNTR1       
  6,708,875 CM        RESET CNTR2       
  ALL ITEMS           PASSWORD LEVEL
"@

$TemplateThatFails = @"
  {Zebraconfig*:{Serial:JJK072821.12Z1220126.23630-01.S.JABI}  
  {Darkness:+20.0}               DARKNESS          
  {PrintSpeed:6 IPS}               PRINT SPEED       
  {TearOff:+000}                TEAR OFF          
  {Applicator:APPLICATOR}          PRINT MODE        
  {MediaType:NON-CONTINUOUS}      MEDIA TYPE        
  {SensorType:WEB}                 SENSOR TYPE       
  {PrintMethod:DIRECT-THERMAL}      PRINT METHOD      
  {PrintWidth:812}                 PRINT WIDTH       
  {LabelLength:1874}                LABEL LENGTH      
  {MaximumLength:9.0IN    228MM}      MAXIMUM LENGTH    
  {SuppliesWarning:DISABLED}            SUPPLIES WARNING  
  {EarlyWarning:MAINT. OFF}          EARLY WARNING     
  {USBComm:CONNECTED}           USB COMM.         
  {External5v:READY}               EXTERNAL 5V       
  {ParallelComm:BIDIRECTIONAL}       PARALLEL COMM.    
  {SerialComm:RS232}               SERIAL COMM.      
  {Baud:9600}                BAUD              
  {DataBits:8 BITS}              DATA BITS         
  {Parity:NONE}                PARITY            
  {HostHandshake:XON/XOFF}            HOST HANDSHAKE    
  {Protocol:NONE}                PROTOCOL          
  {NetworkID:000}                 NETWORK ID        
  {Communications:NORMAL MODE}         COMMUNICATIONS    
  {ControlPrefix:<~>  7EH}            CONTROL PREFIX    
  {FormatPrefix:<^>  5EH}            FORMAT PREFIX     
  {Delimiter:<,>  2CH}            DELIMITER CHAR    
  {ZPLMode:ZPL II}              ZPL MODE          
  {CommandOverride:ACTIVE}              COMMAND OVERRIDE  
  {MediaPowerUp:NO MOTION}           MEDIA POWER UP    
  {HeadClose:NO MOTION}           HEAD CLOSE        
  {Backfeed:OFF}                 BACKFEED          
  {LabelTop:+080}                LABEL TOP         
  {LeftPosition:+0000}               LEFT POSITION     
  {VerifierPort:OFF}                 VERIFIER PORT     
  {ApplicatorPort:MODE 1}              APPLICATOR PORT   
  {ErrorOnPause:ENABLED}             ERROR ON PAUSE    
  {StartPrintSig:PULSE MODE}          START PRINT SIG   
  {ResynchMode:FEED MODE}           RESYNCH MODE      
  {ReprintMode:DISABLED}            REPRINT MODE      
  {WebSensor:048}                 WEB S.            
  {MediaSensor:079}                 MEDIA S.          
  {RibbonSensor:065}                 RIBBON S.         
  {TakeLabel:100}                 TAKE LABEL        
  {MarkSensor:050}                 MARK S.           
  {MarkMedSensor:000}                 MARK MED S.       
  {TrainsGain:002}                 TRANS GAIN        
  {TransBase:040}                 TRANS BASE        
  {TransBright:086}                 TRANS BRIGHT      
  {RibbonGain:082}                 RIBBON GAIN       
  {MarkGain:000}                 MARK GAIN         
  {ModesEnable:DPCSWFX.}            MODES ENABLED     
  {ModesDisabled:.......M}            MODES DISABLED    
   {Resolution:832 8/MM FULL}      RESOLUTION        
  {Firmware:V53.17.21Z <-}       FIRMWARE          
  {XMLSchema:1.3}                 XML SCHEMA        
  {HardwareID:V45 ---------- 19}   HARDWARE ID       
  {Configuration:CUSTOMIZED}          CONFIGURATION     
  {RAM:10840k...........R:} RAM               
  {OnboardFlash:2048k............E:} ONBOARD FLASH     
  {FormatConvert:NONE}                FORMAT CONVERT    
  {P34Interface:*** APPLICATOR}      P34 INTERFACE     
                      TWINAX/COAX ID    
  {IdleDisplay:FW VERSION}          IDLE DISPLAY      
  {RTCDate:11/05/15}            RTC DATE          
  {RTCTime:11:22}               RTC TIME          
  {ZBI:DISABLED}            ZBI               
  {ZBIVersion:2.1}                 ZBI VERSION       
  {NonResetCNTRin:2,641,289 IN}        NONRESET CNTR     
  {ResetCNTR1in:2,641,289 IN}        RESET CNTR1       
  {ResetCNTR2in:2,641,289 IN}        RESET CNTR2       
  {NonResetCNTRcm:6,708,875 CM}        NONRESET CNTR     
  {ResetCNTR1cm:6,708,875 CM}        RESET CNTR1       
  {ResetCNTR2cm:6,708,875 CM}        RESET CNTR2       
  {PasswordLevel:ALL ITEMS}}           PASSWORD LEVEL    
"@

$TemplateThatPartiallyWorks= @"
  {Zebraconfig*:{Serial:JJK072821.12Z1220126.23630-01.S.JABI}  
  {Darkness:+20.0}               DARKNESS          
  {PrintSpeed:6 IPS}               PRINT SPEED       
  {TearOff:+000}                TEAR OFF          
  {Applicator:APPLICATOR}          PRINT MODE        
  {MediaType:NON-CONTINUOUS}      MEDIA TYPE        
  {SensorType:WEB}                 SENSOR TYPE       
  {PrintMethod:DIRECT-THERMAL}      PRINT METHOD      
  {PrintWidth:812}                 PRINT WIDTH       
  {LabelLength:1874}                LABEL LENGTH      
  {MaximumLength:9.0IN    228MM}      MAXIMUM LENGTH    
  {SuppliesWarning:DISABLED}            SUPPLIES WARNING  
  {EarlyWarning:MAINT. OFF}          EARLY WARNING     
  {USBComm:CONNECTED}           USB COMM.         
  {External5v:READY}               EXTERNAL 5V       
  {ParallelComm:BIDIRECTIONAL}       PARALLEL COMM.    
  {SerialComm:RS232}               SERIAL COMM.      
  {Baud:9600}                BAUD              
  {DataBits:8 BITS}              DATA BITS         
  {Parity:NONE}                PARITY            
  {HostHandshake:XON/XOFF}            HOST HANDSHAKE    
  {Protocol:NONE}                PROTOCOL          
  {NetworkID:000}                 NETWORK ID        
  {Communications:NORMAL MODE}         COMMUNICATIONS    
  {ControlPrefix:<~>  7EH}            CONTROL PREFIX    
  {FormatPrefix:<^>  5EH}            FORMAT PREFIX     
  {Delimiter:<,>  2CH}            DELIMITER CHAR    
  {ZPLMode:ZPL II}              ZPL MODE          
  {CommandOverride:ACTIVE}              COMMAND OVERRIDE  
  {MediaPowerUp:NO MOTION}           MEDIA POWER UP    
  {HeadClose:NO MOTION}           HEAD CLOSE        
  {Backfeed:OFF}                 BACKFEED          
  {LabelTop:+080}                LABEL TOP         
  {LeftPosition:+0000}               LEFT POSITION     
  {VerifierPort:OFF}                 VERIFIER PORT     
  {ApplicatorPort:MODE 1}              APPLICATOR PORT   
  {ErrorOnPause:ENABLED}             ERROR ON PAUSE    
  {StartPrintSig:PULSE MODE}          START PRINT SIG   
  {ResynchMode:FEED MODE}           RESYNCH MODE      
  {ReprintMode:DISABLED}            REPRINT MODE      
  {WebSensor:048}                 WEB S.            
  {MediaSensor:079}                 MEDIA S.          
  {RibbonSensor:065}                 RIBBON S.         
  {TakeLabel:100}                 TAKE LABEL        
  {MarkSensor:050}                 MARK S.           
  {MarkMedSensor:000}                 MARK MED S.       
  {TrainsGain:002}                 TRANS GAIN        
  {TransBase:040}                 TRANS BASE        
  {TransBright:086}                 TRANS BRIGHT      
  {RibbonGain:082}                 RIBBON GAIN       
  {MarkGain:000}                 MARK GAIN         
  {ModesEnable:DPCSWFX.}            MODES ENABLED     
  {ModesDisabled:.......M}            MODES DISABLED    
   {Resolution:832 8/MM FULL}      RESOLUTION        
  {Firmware:V53.17.21Z <-}       FIRMWARE          
  {XMLSchema:1.3}                 XML SCHEMA        
  {HardwareID:V45 ---------- 19}   HARDWARE ID       
  {Configuration:CUSTOMIZED}          CONFIGURATION     
  {RAM:10840k...........R:} RAM               
  {OnboardFlash:2048k............E:} ONBOARD FLASH     
  {FormatConvert:NONE}                FORMAT CONVERT    
  {P34Interface:*** APPLICATOR}      P34 INTERFACE     
                      TWINAX/COAX ID    
  {IdleDisplay:FW VERSION}          IDLE DISPLAY      
  {RTCDate:11/05/15}            RTC DATE          
  {RTCTime:11:22}               RTC TIME          
  {ZBI:DISABLED}            ZBI               
  {ZBIVersion:2.1}}                 ZBI VERSION       
"@

Write-Host "Using ConvertFrom-String with the TemplateThatFails"
$Sample | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $TemplateThatFails | select -ExpandProperty ZebraConfig

Write-Host "Using ConvertFrom-String with the TemplateThatPartiallyWorks"
$Sample | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $TemplateThatPartiallyWorks| select -ExpandProperty ZebraConfig
```

I am getting the following results:

```
Using ConvertFrom-String with the TemplateThatFails
ConvertFrom-String : ConvertFrom-String appears to be having trouble parsing your data using the template you've provided. We'd love to take a look at what went wrong, if you'd like to share the data and template used to parse it. We've saved these files to 
C:\Users\alozano\AppData\Local\Temp\usiqowuu.p2u.input.txt and C:\Users\alozano\AppData\Local\Temp\usiqowuu.p2u-0.template.txt - feel free to attach them in a mail to psdmfb@microsoft.com. We will review all submissions, although we can't guarantee a response.
At line:231 char:16
+ ... codedHTML | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $TemplateThatFails |  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [ConvertFrom-String], ResultNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ResultNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StringManipulation.ConvertFromStringCommand

Using ConvertFrom-String with the TemplateThatPartiallyWorks


Serial          : JJK072821.12Z1220126.23630-01.S.JABI
Darkness        : +20.0
PrintSpeed      : 6 IPS
TearOff         : +000
Applicator      : APPLICATOR
MediaType       : NON-CONTINUOUS
SensorType      : WEB
PrintMethod     : DIRECT-THERMAL
PrintWidth      : 812
LabelLength     : 1874
MaximumLength   : 9.0IN    228MM
SuppliesWarning : DISABLED
EarlyWarning    : MAINT. OFF
USBComm         : CONNECTED
External5v      : READY
ParallelComm    : BIDIRECTIONAL
SerialComm      : RS232
Baud            : 9600
DataBits        : 8 BITS
Parity          : NONE
HostHandshake   : XON/XOFF
Protocol        : NONE
NetworkID       : 000
Communications  : NORMAL MODE
ControlPrefix   : <~>  7EH
FormatPrefix    : <^>  5EH
Delimiter       : <,>  2CH
ZPLMode         : ZPL II
CommandOverride : ACTIVE
MediaPowerUp    : NO MOTION
HeadClose       : NO MOTION
Backfeed        : OFF
LabelTop        : +080
LeftPosition    : +0000
VerifierPort    : OFF
ApplicatorPort  : MODE 1
ErrorOnPause    : ENABLED
StartPrintSig   : PULSE MODE
ResynchMode     : FEED MODE
ReprintMode     : DISABLED
WebSensor       : 048
MediaSensor     : 079
RibbonSensor    : 065
TakeLabel       : 100
MarkSensor      : 050
MarkMedSensor   : 000
TrainsGain      : 002
TransBase       : 040
TransBright     : 086
RibbonGain      : 082
MarkGain        : 000
ModesEnable     : DPCSWFX.
ModesDisabled   : .......M
Resolution      : 832 8/MM FULL
Firmware        : V53.17.21Z <-
XMLSchema       : 1.3
HardwareID      : V45 ---------- 19
Configuration   : CUSTOMIZED
RAM             : 10840k...........R:
OnboardFlash    : 2048k............E:
FormatConvert   : NONE
P34Interface    : *** APPLICATOR
IdleDisplay     : FW VERSION
RTCDate         : 11/05/15
RTCTime         : 11:22
ZBI             : DISABLED
ZBIVersion      : 2.1
```

These are the 7 lines that are at the end of `$TemplateThatFails` and that I have left out of `$TemplateThatPartiallyWorks`:

```
{NonResetCNTRin:2,641,289 IN}        NONRESET CNTR     
{ResetCNTR1in:2,641,289 IN}        RESET CNTR1       
{ResetCNTR2in:2,641,289 IN}        RESET CNTR2       
{NonResetCNTRcm:6,708,875 CM}        NONRESET CNTR     
{ResetCNTR1cm:6,708,875 CM}        RESET CNTR1       
{ResetCNTR2cm:6,708,875 CM}        RESET CNTR2       
{PasswordLevel:ALL ITEMS}}           PASSWORD LEVEL
```

System Info:

```
Operating System: Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64-bit (6.3, Build 9600) (9600.winblue_r9.150322-1500)
Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
System Model: Latitude E7450
BIOS: BIOS Date: 12/29/14 05:36:41 Ver: A02.00 
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.3GHz
Memory: 8192MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 8082MB RAM
```

Comment: Thanks, did that help at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My setup is quite the same (i5/16Gb/Win8.1 64bit/PS 5.0.10514.6).

This is a bit crazy ; only the last line is a problem.

1 - If you isolate it completely and make it the only line in the template and in the sample, it works.

Code :

```
$Sample = @"  
  ALL ITEMS           PASSWORD LEVEL
"@

$TemplateThatFails = @"
  {Zebraconfig*:{PasswordLevel:ALL ITEMS}}           PASSWORD LEVEL    
"@

Write-Host "Using ConvertFrom-String with the TemplateThatFails"
$startTime = Get-Date
$Sample | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $TemplateThatFails | select -ExpandProperty ZebraConfig
$endTime = Get-Date
$elapsed = "{0:N2}" -f (New-TimeSpan $startTime $endTime).TotalSeconds
"$elapsed seconds elapsed"
```

Output :

```
PasswordLevel
-------------
ALL ITEMS    
0,13 seconds elapsed
```

2 - If you move it just above the previous one (in the sample and in the template), you don't get any error but the data is mixed up.

Code :

```
$Sample = @"
  JJK072821.12Z1220126.23630-01.S.JABI  
  +20.0               DARKNESS          
  6 IPS               PRINT SPEED       
  +000                TEAR OFF          
  APPLICATOR          PRINT MODE        
  NON-CONTINUOUS      MEDIA TYPE        
  WEB                 SENSOR TYPE       
  DIRECT-THERMAL      PRINT METHOD      
  812                 PRINT WIDTH       
  1874                LABEL LENGTH      
  9.0IN    228MM      MAXIMUM LENGTH    
  DISABLED            SUPPLIES WARNING  
  MAINT. OFF          EARLY WARNING     
  CONNECTED           USB COMM.         
  READY               EXTERNAL 5V       
  BIDIRECTIONAL       PARALLEL COMM.    
  RS232               SERIAL COMM.      
  9600                BAUD              
  8 BITS              DATA BITS         
  NONE                PARITY            
  XON/XOFF            HOST HANDSHAKE    
  NONE                PROTOCOL          
  000                 NETWORK ID        
  NORMAL MODE         COMMUNICATIONS    
  <~>  7EH            CONTROL PREFIX    
  <^>  5EH            FORMAT PREFIX     
  <,>  2CH            DELIMITER CHAR    
  ZPL II              ZPL MODE          
  ACTIVE              COMMAND OVERRIDE  
  NO MOTION           MEDIA POWER UP    
  NO MOTION           HEAD CLOSE        
  OFF                 BACKFEED          
  +080                LABEL TOP         
  +0000               LEFT POSITION     
  OFF                 VERIFIER PORT     
  MODE 1              APPLICATOR PORT   
  ENABLED             ERROR ON PAUSE    
  PULSE MODE          START PRINT SIG   
  FEED MODE           RESYNCH MODE      
  DISABLED            REPRINT MODE      
  048                 WEB S.            
  079                 MEDIA S.          
  065                 RIBBON S.         
  100                 TAKE LABEL        
  050                 MARK S.           
  000                 MARK MED S.       
  002                 TRANS GAIN        
  040                 TRANS BASE        
  086                 TRANS BRIGHT      
  082                 RIBBON GAIN       
  000                 MARK GAIN         
  DPCSWFX.            MODES ENABLED     
  .......M            MODES DISABLED    
   832 8/MM FULL      RESOLUTION        
  V53.17.21Z <-       FIRMWARE          
  1.3                 XML SCHEMA        
  V45 ---------- 19   HARDWARE ID       
  CUSTOMIZED          CONFIGURATION     
  10840k...........R: RAM               
  2048k............E: ONBOARD FLASH     
  NONE                FORMAT CONVERT    
  *** APPLICATOR      P34 INTERFACE     
                      TWINAX/COAX ID    
  FW VERSION          IDLE DISPLAY      
  11/05/15            RTC DATE          
  11:22               RTC TIME          
  DISABLED            ZBI               
  2.1                 ZBI VERSION       
  2,641,289 IN        NONRESET CNTR     
  2,641,289 IN        RESET CNTR1       
  2,641,289 IN        RESET CNTR2       
  6,708,875 CM        NONRESET CNTR     
  6,708,875 CM        RESET CNTR1       
  ALL ITEMS           PASSWORD LEVEL
  6,708,875 CM        RESET CNTR2       
"@

$TemplateThatFails = @"
  {Zebraconfig*:{Serial:JJK072821.12Z1220126.23630-01.S.JABI}  
  {Darkness:+20.0}               DARKNESS          
  {PrintSpeed:6 IPS}               PRINT SPEED       
  {TearOff:+000}                TEAR OFF          
  {Applicator:APPLICATOR}          PRINT MODE        
  {MediaType:NON-CONTINUOUS}      MEDIA TYPE        
  {SensorType:WEB}                 SENSOR TYPE       
  {PrintMethod:DIRECT-THERMAL}      PRINT METHOD      
  {PrintWidth:812}                 PRINT WIDTH       
  {LabelLength:1874}                LABEL LENGTH      
  {MaximumLength:9.0IN    228MM}      MAXIMUM LENGTH    
  {SuppliesWarning:DISABLED}            SUPPLIES WARNING  
  {EarlyWarning:MAINT. OFF}          EARLY WARNING     
  {USBComm:CONNECTED}           USB COMM.         
  {External5v:READY}               EXTERNAL 5V       
  {ParallelComm:BIDIRECTIONAL}       PARALLEL COMM.    
  {SerialComm:RS232}               SERIAL COMM.      
  {Baud:9600}                BAUD              
  {DataBits:8 BITS}              DATA BITS         
  {Parity:NONE}                PARITY            
  {HostHandshake:XON/XOFF}            HOST HANDSHAKE    
  {Protocol:NONE}                PROTOCOL          
  {NetworkID:000}                 NETWORK ID        
  {Communications:NORMAL MODE}         COMMUNICATIONS    
  {ControlPrefix:<~>  7EH}            CONTROL PREFIX    
  {FormatPrefix:<^>  5EH}            FORMAT PREFIX     
  {Delimiter:<,>  2CH}            DELIMITER CHAR    
  {ZPLMode:ZPL II}              ZPL MODE          
  {CommandOverride:ACTIVE}              COMMAND OVERRIDE  
  {MediaPowerUp:NO MOTION}           MEDIA POWER UP    
  {HeadClose:NO MOTION}           HEAD CLOSE        
  {Backfeed:OFF}                 BACKFEED          
  {LabelTop:+080}                LABEL TOP         
  {LeftPosition:+0000}               LEFT POSITION     
  {VerifierPort:OFF}                 VERIFIER PORT     
  {ApplicatorPort:MODE 1}              APPLICATOR PORT   
  {ErrorOnPause:ENABLED}             ERROR ON PAUSE    
  {StartPrintSig:PULSE MODE}          START PRINT SIG   
  {ResynchMode:FEED MODE}           RESYNCH MODE      
  {ReprintMode:DISABLED}            REPRINT MODE      
  {WebSensor:048}                 WEB S.            
  {MediaSensor:079}                 MEDIA S.          
  {RibbonSensor:065}                 RIBBON S.         
  {TakeLabel:100}                 TAKE LABEL        
  {MarkSensor:050}                 MARK S.           
  {MarkMedSensor:000}                 MARK MED S.       
  {TrainsGain:002}                 TRANS GAIN        
  {TransBase:040}                 TRANS BASE        
  {TransBright:086}                 TRANS BRIGHT      
  {RibbonGain:082}                 RIBBON GAIN       
  {MarkGain:000}                 MARK GAIN         
  {ModesEnable:DPCSWFX.}            MODES ENABLED     
  {ModesDisabled:.......M}            MODES DISABLED    
   {Resolution:832 8/MM FULL}      RESOLUTION        
  {Firmware:V53.17.21Z <-}       FIRMWARE          
  {XMLSchema:1.3}                 XML SCHEMA        
  {HardwareID:V45 ---------- 19}   HARDWARE ID       
  {Configuration:CUSTOMIZED}          CONFIGURATION     
  {RAM:10840k...........R:} RAM               
  {OnboardFlash:2048k............E:} ONBOARD FLASH     
  {FormatConvert:NONE}                FORMAT CONVERT    
  {P34Interface:*** APPLICATOR}      P34 INTERFACE     
                      TWINAX/COAX ID    
  {IdleDisplay:FW VERSION}          IDLE DISPLAY      
  {RTCDate:11/05/15}            RTC DATE          
  {RTCTime:11:22}               RTC TIME          
  {ZBI:DISABLED}            ZBI               
  {ZBIVersion:2.1}                 ZBI VERSION       
  {NonResetCNTRin:2,641,289 IN}        NONRESET CNTR     
  {ResetCNTR1in:2,641,289 IN}        RESET CNTR1       
  {ResetCNTR2in:2,641,289 IN}        RESET CNTR2       
  {NonResetCNTRcm:6,708,875 CM}        NONRESET CNTR     
  {ResetCNTR1cm:6,708,875 CM}        RESET CNTR1       
  {PasswordLevel:ALL ITEMS}           PASSWORD LEVEL    
  {ResetCNTR2cm:6,708,875 CM}}        RESET CNTR2       
"@

Write-Host "Using ConvertFrom-String with the TemplateThatFails"
$startTime = Get-Date
$Sample | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $TemplateThatFails | select -ExpandProperty ZebraConfig
$endTime = Get-Date
$elapsed = "{0:N2}" -f (New-TimeSpan $startTime $endTime).TotalSeconds
"$elapsed seconds elapsed"
```

Output :

```
Serial          : JJK072821.12Z1220126.23630-01.S.JABI
Darkness        : +20.0
PrintSpeed      : 6 IPS
TearOff         : +000
Applicator      : APPLICATOR
MediaType       : NON-CONTINUOUS
SensorType      : WEB
PrintMethod     : DIRECT-THERMAL
PrintWidth      : 812
LabelLength     : 1874
MaximumLength   : 9.0IN    228MM
SuppliesWarning : DISABLED
EarlyWarning    : MAINT. OFF
USBComm         : CONNECTED
External5v      : READY
ParallelComm    : BIDIRECTIONAL
SerialComm      : RS232
Baud            : 9600
DataBits        : 8 BITS
Parity          : NONE
HostHandshake   : XON/XOFF
Protocol        : NONE
NetworkID       : 000
Communications  : NORMAL MODE
ControlPrefix   : <~>  7EH
FormatPrefix    : <^>  5EH
Delimiter       : <,>  2CH
ZPLMode         : ZPL II
CommandOverride : ACTIVE
MediaPowerUp    : NO MOTION
HeadClose       : NO MOTION
Backfeed        : OFF
LabelTop        : +080
LeftPosition    : +0000
VerifierPort    : OFF
ApplicatorPort  : MODE 1
ErrorOnPause    : ENABLED
StartPrintSig   : PULSE MODE
ResynchMode     : FEED MODE
ReprintMode     : DISABLED
WebSensor       : 048
MediaSensor     : 079
RibbonSensor    : 065
TakeLabel       : 100
MarkSensor      : 050
MarkMedSensor   : 000
TrainsGain      : 002
TransBase       : 040
TransBright     : 086
RibbonGain      : 082
MarkGain        : 000
ModesEnable     : DPCSWFX.
ModesDisabled   : .......M
Resolution      : 832 8/MM FULL
Firmware        : V53.17.21Z <-
XMLSchema       : 1.3
HardwareID      : V45 ---------- 19
Configuration   : CUSTOMIZED
RAM             : 10840k...........R:
OnboardFlash    : 2048k............E:
FormatConvert   : NONE
P34Interface    : *** APPLICATOR
IdleDisplay     : FW VERSION
RTCDate         : 11/05/15
RTCTime         : 11:22
ZBI             : DISABLED
ZBIVersion      : 2.1
NonResetCNTRin  : 2,641,289 IN
ResetCNTR1in    : 2,641,289 IN
ResetCNTR2in    : 2,641,289 IN
NonResetCNTRcm  : 6,708,875 CM
ResetCNTR1cm    : 6,708,875 CM
PasswordLevel   : CM        RESET
ResetCNTR2cm    : 6,708,875 CM

36,58 seconds elapsed
```

3 - If you move it above `ZBI VERSION` (sample + template), which is the last line in the partially working template, everything is fine.

Code :

```
$Sample = @"
  JJK072821.12Z1220126.23630-01.S.JABI  
  +20.0               DARKNESS          
  6 IPS               PRINT SPEED       
  +000                TEAR OFF          
  APPLICATOR          PRINT MODE        
  NON-CONTINUOUS      MEDIA TYPE        
  WEB                 SENSOR TYPE       
  DIRECT-THERMAL      PRINT METHOD      
  812                 PRINT WIDTH       
  1874                LABEL LENGTH      
  9.0IN    228MM      MAXIMUM LENGTH    
  DISABLED            SUPPLIES WARNING  
  MAINT. OFF          EARLY WARNING     
  CONNECTED           USB COMM.         
  READY               EXTERNAL 5V       
  BIDIRECTIONAL       PARALLEL COMM.    
  RS232               SERIAL COMM.      
  9600                BAUD              
  8 BITS              DATA BITS         
  NONE                PARITY            
  XON/XOFF            HOST HANDSHAKE    
  NONE                PROTOCOL          
  000                 NETWORK ID        
  NORMAL MODE         COMMUNICATIONS    
  <~>  7EH            CONTROL PREFIX    
  <^>  5EH            FORMAT PREFIX     
  <,>  2CH            DELIMITER CHAR    
  ZPL II              ZPL MODE          
  ACTIVE              COMMAND OVERRIDE  
  NO MOTION           MEDIA POWER UP    
  NO MOTION           HEAD CLOSE        
  OFF                 BACKFEED          
  +080                LABEL TOP         
  +0000               LEFT POSITION     
  OFF                 VERIFIER PORT     
  MODE 1              APPLICATOR PORT   
  ENABLED             ERROR ON PAUSE    
  PULSE MODE          START PRINT SIG   
  FEED MODE           RESYNCH MODE      
  DISABLED            REPRINT MODE      
  048                 WEB S.            
  079                 MEDIA S.          
  065                 RIBBON S.         
  100                 TAKE LABEL        
  050                 MARK S.           
  000                 MARK MED S.       
  002                 TRANS GAIN        
  040                 TRANS BASE        
  086                 TRANS BRIGHT      
  082                 RIBBON GAIN       
  000                 MARK GAIN         
  DPCSWFX.            MODES ENABLED     
  .......M            MODES DISABLED    
   832 8/MM FULL      RESOLUTION        
  V53.17.21Z <-       FIRMWARE          
  1.3                 XML SCHEMA        
  V45 ---------- 19   HARDWARE ID       
  CUSTOMIZED          CONFIGURATION     
  10840k...........R: RAM               
  2048k............E: ONBOARD FLASH     
  NONE                FORMAT CONVERT    
  *** APPLICATOR      P34 INTERFACE     
                      TWINAX/COAX ID    
  FW VERSION          IDLE DISPLAY      
  11/05/15            RTC DATE          
  11:22               RTC TIME          
  DISABLED            ZBI               
  ALL ITEMS           PASSWORD LEVEL
  2.1                 ZBI VERSION       
  2,641,289 IN        NONRESET CNTR     
  2,641,289 IN        RESET CNTR1       
  2,641,289 IN        RESET CNTR2       
  6,708,875 CM        NONRESET CNTR     
  6,708,875 CM        RESET CNTR1       
  6,708,875 CM        RESET CNTR2       
"@

$TemplateThatFails = @"
  {Zebraconfig*:{Serial:JJK072821.12Z1220126.23630-01.S.JABI}  
  {Darkness:+20.0}               DARKNESS          
  {PrintSpeed:6 IPS}               PRINT SPEED       
  {TearOff:+000}                TEAR OFF          
  {Applicator:APPLICATOR}          PRINT MODE        
  {MediaType:NON-CONTINUOUS}      MEDIA TYPE        
  {SensorType:WEB}                 SENSOR TYPE       
  {PrintMethod:DIRECT-THERMAL}      PRINT METHOD      
  {PrintWidth:812}                 PRINT WIDTH       
  {LabelLength:1874}                LABEL LENGTH      
  {MaximumLength:9.0IN    228MM}      MAXIMUM LENGTH    
  {SuppliesWarning:DISABLED}            SUPPLIES WARNING  
  {EarlyWarning:MAINT. OFF}          EARLY WARNING     
  {USBComm:CONNECTED}           USB COMM.         
  {External5v:READY}               EXTERNAL 5V       
  {ParallelComm:BIDIRECTIONAL}       PARALLEL COMM.    
  {SerialComm:RS232}               SERIAL COMM.      
  {Baud:9600}                BAUD              
  {DataBits:8 BITS}              DATA BITS         
  {Parity:NONE}                PARITY            
  {HostHandshake:XON/XOFF}            HOST HANDSHAKE    
  {Protocol:NONE}                PROTOCOL          
  {NetworkID:000}                 NETWORK ID        
  {Communications:NORMAL MODE}         COMMUNICATIONS    
  {ControlPrefix:<~>  7EH}            CONTROL PREFIX    
  {FormatPrefix:<^>  5EH}            FORMAT PREFIX     
  {Delimiter:<,>  2CH}            DELIMITER CHAR    
  {ZPLMode:ZPL II}              ZPL MODE          
  {CommandOverride:ACTIVE}              COMMAND OVERRIDE  
  {MediaPowerUp:NO MOTION}           MEDIA POWER UP    
  {HeadClose:NO MOTION}           HEAD CLOSE        
  {Backfeed:OFF}                 BACKFEED          
  {LabelTop:+080}                LABEL TOP         
  {LeftPosition:+0000}               LEFT POSITION     
  {VerifierPort:OFF}                 VERIFIER PORT     
  {ApplicatorPort:MODE 1}              APPLICATOR PORT   
  {ErrorOnPause:ENABLED}             ERROR ON PAUSE    
  {StartPrintSig:PULSE MODE}          START PRINT SIG   
  {ResynchMode:FEED MODE}           RESYNCH MODE      
  {ReprintMode:DISABLED}            REPRINT MODE      
  {WebSensor:048}                 WEB S.            
  {MediaSensor:079}                 MEDIA S.          
  {RibbonSensor:065}                 RIBBON S.         
  {TakeLabel:100}                 TAKE LABEL        
  {MarkSensor:050}                 MARK S.           
  {MarkMedSensor:000}                 MARK MED S.       
  {TrainsGain:002}                 TRANS GAIN        
  {TransBase:040}                 TRANS BASE        
  {TransBright:086}                 TRANS BRIGHT      
  {RibbonGain:082}                 RIBBON GAIN       
  {MarkGain:000}                 MARK GAIN         
  {ModesEnable:DPCSWFX.}            MODES ENABLED     
  {ModesDisabled:.......M}            MODES DISABLED    
   {Resolution:832 8/MM FULL}      RESOLUTION        
  {Firmware:V53.17.21Z <-}       FIRMWARE          
  {XMLSchema:1.3}                 XML SCHEMA        
  {HardwareID:V45 ---------- 19}   HARDWARE ID       
  {Configuration:CUSTOMIZED}          CONFIGURATION     
  {RAM:10840k...........R:} RAM               
  {OnboardFlash:2048k............E:} ONBOARD FLASH     
  {FormatConvert:NONE}                FORMAT CONVERT    
  {P34Interface:*** APPLICATOR}      P34 INTERFACE     
                      TWINAX/COAX ID    
  {IdleDisplay:FW VERSION}          IDLE DISPLAY      
  {RTCDate:11/05/15}            RTC DATE          
  {RTCTime:11:22}               RTC TIME          
  {ZBI:DISABLED}            ZBI               
  {PasswordLevel:ALL ITEMS}           PASSWORD LEVEL    
  {ZBIVersion:2.1}                 ZBI VERSION       
  {NonResetCNTRin:2,641,289 IN}        NONRESET CNTR     
  {ResetCNTR1in:2,641,289 IN}        RESET CNTR1       
  {ResetCNTR2in:2,641,289 IN}        RESET CNTR2       
  {NonResetCNTRcm:6,708,875 CM}        NONRESET CNTR     
  {ResetCNTR1cm:6,708,875 CM}        RESET CNTR1       
  {ResetCNTR2cm:6,708,875 CM}}        RESET CNTR2       
"@

Write-Host "Using ConvertFrom-String with the TemplateThatFails"
$startTime = Get-Date
$Sample | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $TemplateThatFails | select -ExpandProperty ZebraConfig
$endTime = Get-Date
$elapsed = "{0:N2}" -f (New-TimeSpan $startTime $endTime).TotalSeconds
"$elapsed seconds elapsed"
```

Output :

```
Serial          : JJK072821.12Z1220126.23630-01.S.JABI
Darkness        : +20.0
PrintSpeed      : 6 IPS
TearOff         : +000
Applicator      : APPLICATOR
MediaType       : NON-CONTINUOUS
SensorType      : WEB
PrintMethod     : DIRECT-THERMAL
PrintWidth      : 812
LabelLength     : 1874
MaximumLength   : 9.0IN    228MM
SuppliesWarning : DISABLED
EarlyWarning    : MAINT. OFF
USBComm         : CONNECTED
External5v      : READY
ParallelComm    : BIDIRECTIONAL
SerialComm      : RS232
Baud            : 9600
DataBits        : 8 BITS
Parity          : NONE
HostHandshake   : XON/XOFF
Protocol        : NONE
NetworkID       : 000
Communications  : NORMAL MODE
ControlPrefix   : <~>  7EH
FormatPrefix    : <^>  5EH
Delimiter       : <,>  2CH
ZPLMode         : ZPL II
CommandOverride : ACTIVE
MediaPowerUp    : NO MOTION
HeadClose       : NO MOTION
Backfeed        : OFF
LabelTop        : +080
LeftPosition    : +0000
VerifierPort    : OFF
ApplicatorPort  : MODE 1
ErrorOnPause    : ENABLED
StartPrintSig   : PULSE MODE
ResynchMode     : FEED MODE
ReprintMode     : DISABLED
WebSensor       : 048
MediaSensor     : 079
RibbonSensor    : 065
TakeLabel       : 100
MarkSensor      : 050
MarkMedSensor   : 000
TrainsGain      : 002
TransBase       : 040
TransBright     : 086
RibbonGain      : 082
MarkGain        : 000
ModesEnable     : DPCSWFX.
ModesDisabled   : .......M
Resolution      : 832 8/MM FULL
Firmware        : V53.17.21Z <-
XMLSchema       : 1.3
HardwareID      : V45 ---------- 19
Configuration   : CUSTOMIZED
RAM             : 10840k...........R:
OnboardFlash    : 2048k............E:
FormatConvert   : NONE
P34Interface    : *** APPLICATOR
IdleDisplay     : FW VERSION
RTCDate         : 11/05/15
RTCTime         : 11:22
ZBI             : DISABLED
PasswordLevel   : ALL ITEMS
ZBIVersion      : 2.1
NonResetCNTRin  : 2,641,289 IN
ResetCNTR1in    : 2,641,289 IN
ResetCNTR2in    : 2,641,289 IN
NonResetCNTRcm  : 6,708,875 CM
ResetCNTR1cm    : 6,708,875 CM
ResetCNTR2cm    : 6,708,875 CM

36,32 seconds elapsed
```

I really don't understand what's going on, but I have managed to suppress the error so I hope this will point you in the right direction.

PS : why is this so long to run ?!